# Can users/enterprises download and resign IPA within Apple ToS?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, mobile-device-management

I have an app in the Apple App Store, and am curious whether Apple ToS permits end-users and enterprises to download my (or any) app and redistribute them using enterprise certificates (e.g. MDM) or ad-hoc Apple developer distribution?

I haven't been able to find any direct information regarding Apples stance on the matter.

As far as I know, tools exists that can change the bundle id and then using a custom provisioning profile resigning and distribution is possible outside of the Apple App Store.

(Also asked on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971753/can-users-enterprises-download-and-resign-ipa-within-apple-tos)

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites.  If the mods believe your question should be posted on a different site, they'll move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of the EULA you give to the user in iTunes connect. Apple has a standard default Eula you can override it if you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW13

Comment: Not begin a lawyer, I interpret the following sentence from the standard EULA that it is not permitted:

You may not copy (except as expressly permitted by this license and the Usage Rules), decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, attempt to derive the source code of, modify, or create derivative works of the Licensed Application, any updates, or any part thereof

From: http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/